# HasMap Hash code implemetation

Tags: hashmap

I have some confusion about hash code, I am trying to understand how hash map uses hash code and equals method and I wrote the below code, the problem is even if I give the key to be Integer Object, its making use of the hash code implementation of my overridden hash code method in employee Object(which I am storing as value).

As per my understanding since the Key is Integer it should make use of the hash code method of the Object class and not my hash code implementation.

If this is using my hash code implementation, it should treat the keys to be duplicate(which it does in case I use employee.getEmpid() ) and should not store the keys.

I have debugged it and the flow always goes to my implementation of the hash code method in the below Employee Class.

## Employee Test

```
  public class EmployeeTest {

        private static final Map<Integer, Employee> hmap = new HashMap<>();

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Satya", "IT");
            Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Deep", "HR");
            Employee e3 = new Employee(1, "Rajeev", "OPERATIONS");
            Employee e4 = new Employee(2, "Lovely", "FINANCE");

            hmap.put(1, e1);
            hmap.put(2, e2);
            hmap.put(3, e3);
            hmap.put(4, e4);

            System.out.println(hmap.put(1, e1).hashCode());
            System.out.println(hmap.put(2, e2).hashCode());
            System.out.println(hmap.put(3, e3).hashCode());
            System.out.println(hmap.put(4, e4).hashCode());

            System.out.println(e1.equals(e3));
            System.out.println(hmap.put(1, e1).equals(hmap.put(3, e3)));
            Set<Entry<Integer, Employee>> hset = hmap.entrySet();

            //Set<String> hashset = hmap.keySet();

            hset.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach( e -> System.out.println(e) );

        }
    }
```

## Employee

```
   public class Employee {

        private String empname, empdept;

        private int empid;

        public Employee( int empid, String empname, String empdept )  {

            this.empid = empid;
            this.empname = empname;
            this.empdept = empdept;
        }

        public int hashCode(){

            return this.empid;
        }

        public boolean equals(Employee e){

            return this.empid == e.empid;
        }

        public int getEmpid() {
            return empid;
        }

        public void setEmpid(int empid) {
            this.empid = empid;
        }

        public String getEmpname() {
            return empname;
        }
        public void setEmpname(String empname) {
            this.empname = empname;
        }

        public String getEmpdept() {
            return empdept;
        }

        public void setEmpdept(String empdept) {
            this.empdept = empdept;
        }


    }
```

## Output

```
1
2
1
2
true
true
1=org.infozech.collection.Map.Employee@1
2=org.infozech.collection.Map.Employee@2
3=org.infozech.collection.Map.Employee@1
4=org.infozech.collection.Map.Employee@2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the explanation for this... The e1 == e3 and e2 == e4 have the same hash code and they end up in the same bucket respectively. The reason for my flow going into the employee hash code is, I have not overridden toString() in employee class and its using toString() of the Object class internally which uses hashcode() of the employee class internally to print it via System.out.prinln(). So above answer that hashing is done on value for storing keys is wrong as given by Piotrek Hryciuk . Hash map has nothing to do with the hash code of value for storing into the hash table. Its always the has code of the key rather.

Answer (score 0):

You have overriden `hashcode()` in your `Employee` class in a proper manner - (it's not a perfect hashing function (you can read more about hashing in e.g.  [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683))).

When you are using a `HashMap`, hashing is used for *values* of the map. That is the reason your debugger enters `Employee`'s `hashcode()` method.

> If this is using my hash code implementation, it should treat the keys to be duplicate(which it does in case I use employee.getEmpid() ) and should not store the keys.

This is **not** true. If the two objects have the same hashcode, they just end up in the same *bucket*, which in fact means that they are stored in a list one after another. `HashSet` provides feature similar to what you have described - it does not allow duplicates. If you try to put two equal objects into a `HashSet` only one will be stored.

`hashcode()` and `equals()` are **very important** aspects of Java programming. I recommend you reading mentioned above book, or at least [this article](http://www.ideyatech.com/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/).

Comment: Can you please explain what is hapeening in case I give the key to be e1.getEmpid() ,..... , e4.getEmpid() instead of 1,2,3,4 ? I understand that in the later case( when the key is 1,2,3,4) the objects end up in the same bucket, so you mean e3 is in the same bucket as e1 and e2 and e4 are in the same bucket.. But how can I iterate them ?